# POSTGRESQL copy jsonb value to new column

Tags: json, postgresql, insert

I want extract a json value from a column and insert it into a new one.

Example row as an insert statement copied:

```
INSERT INTO "table_name".("booking_number","arrival_date","departure_date","custom_fields","customer_id","import_id","id","at_table","a_la_carte","value")
VALUES
(E'00000007',E'2019-01-02 12:00:00',E'2020-02-05 12:00:00',E'[{"protelSurname": "Smith", "servicio_tags": ["protel-info"], "protelUniqueID": "[{\\"ID\\":\\"294623726\\",\\"Type\\":\\"21\\",\\"ID_Context\\":\\"GHA\\"},{\\"ID\\":\\"4842148\\",\\"Type\\":\\"1\\",\\"ID_Context\\":\\"protelIO\\"}]", "protelGivenName": "Seth"}, {"value": "3/3/3/3/3", "display_name": "Personen Anzahl", "servicio_tags": ["person-number-info"]}, {"value": "en", "display_name": "Sprache", "servicio_tags": ["language"]}, {"value": " Robotics", "display_name": "Begleiter", "servicio_tags": ["accompanied-guests"]}, {"value": "2. Januar 2019", "display_name": "Anreise", "servicio_tags": ["arrival"]}, {"value": "5. Februar 2020", "display_name": "Abreise", "servicio_tags": ["departure"]}, {"value": "EBROV RO", "display_name": "Rate Code", "servicio_tags": ["price-type"]}, {"value": "SSV", "display_name": "Zimmer Typ", "servicio_tags": ["room-type"]}, {"value": "2013", "display_name": "Zimmernummer", "servicio_tags": ["room-number"]}, {"value": "Australia", "display_name": "Nation", "servicio_tags": ["nation"]}, {"value": "", "display_name": "Gruppe", "servicio_tags": ["group-name"]}]',1,36020,369528,FALSE,FALSE,E'{"protelSurname": "Smith", "servicio_tags": ["protel-info"], "protelUniqueID": "[{\\"ID\\":\\"294623726\\",\\"Type\\":\\"21\\",\\"ID_Context\\":\\"GHA\\"},{\\"ID\\":\\"4842148\\",\\"Type\\":\\"1\\",\\"ID_Context\\":\\"protelIO\\"}]", "protelGivenName": "Seth"}');
```

I want to extract the protelUniqueID with the servicio-tag ["protel-info"]. In the best case only the ID value. In this case 294623726.
Then I want to create a new column named guest_profile_id in this table named guest_group and insert this value in for the same row.

So I think this needs to be done by the following steps:

1. Creating new column
2. Query id from json column
3. Insert id to new column

My try so far for step 2)

`SELECT *  FROM guest_group gg cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(custom_fields)  WHERE    value @> '{"servicio_tags": ["protel-info"]}'::jsonb AND gg.customer_id = 1`

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `protelUniqueID` is a list. You need the only first `ID` from a list as I understood.

> Note! `"protelUniqueID": "[{\\"ID\\": ....` looks like strange format. Is like `json` as `string` inside `json`. Anyway I share solution for your description.

```
CREATE TABLE my_tbl (custom_fields jsonb);
INSERT INTO my_tbl (custom_fields)
VALUES
(
E'{"protelSurname": "Smith", "servicio_tags": ["protel-info"], "protelUniqueID": "[{\\"ID\\":\\"294623726\\",\\"Type\\":\\"21\\",\\"ID_Context\\":\\"GHA\\"},{\\"ID\\":\\"4842148\\",\\"Type\\":\\"1\\",\\"ID_Context\\":\\"protelIO\\"}]", "protelGivenName": "Seth"}'
);
```

Let's try to select our `ID`(294623726):

```
SELECT
    custom_fields::json->'servicio_tags' AS tags,
    CAST(CAST(CAST(custom_fields::json->'protelUniqueID' AS jsonb)->>0 AS jsonb)->>0 AS jsonb)->>'ID' AS protel_first_id
FROM my_tbl;
-- tags,protel_first_id
--["protel-info"],294623726
```

All what we need is just add a column + `update`

```
ALTER TABLE my_tbl ADD COLUMN guest_profile_id INTEGER DEFAULT NULL;
UPDATE my_tbl set guest_profile_id = CAST(CAST(CAST(CAST(custom_fields::json->'protelUniqueID' AS jsonb)->>0 AS jsonb)->>0 AS jsonb)->>'ID' AS INTEGER) WHERE guest_profile_id IS NULL;
```

[db-fiddle example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/228)

**Note!** You can remove 1 `CAST` if you'll use clear format:

```
INSERT INTO my_tbl (custom_fields)
VALUES
(
E'{"protelUniqueID": [{"ID":"294623726","Type":"21","ID_Context":"GHA"},{"ID":"4842148","Type":"1","ID_Context":"protelIO"}]}'
);

SELECT
    CAST(CAST(custom_fields::json->'protelUniqueID' AS jsonb)->>0 AS jsonb)->>'ID' AS protel_first_id
FROM my_tbl;
```

Hope this helps.